# pyproject.toml configuration to ignore a specific path?

Tags: python, pytest, pyproject.toml

Are there any ways to set a path to ignore in `pyproject.toml` like:

```ini
#pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
ignore = ["path/to/test"]
```

Instead of using `addopts`:

```ini
#pyproject.toml
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "--ignore=path/to/test"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The list of configuration options you can add in the `[tool.pytest.ini_options]` (or `pytest.ini`) is documented in https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#configuration-options, which includes `addopts`, `norecursedirs`, etc. As of now, there is no such option like `ignore` for test discovery that can be listed in `pytest.ini` or `pyproject.toml`.

However, you have some alternatives:

#### Use `testpaths`

https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-testpaths

It would be a good idea to maintain a whitelist (includelist) to run tests on, like the package or test suites. This sets a list of directories that should be searched for test discovery.

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
testpaths = your_package testing
```

#### Use `collect_ignore` in `testconf.py`

https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/pythoncollection.html#customizing-test-collection
https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#global-variables

You can add a global variable `collect_ignore` or `connect_ignore_glob` in `conftest.py` to customize which files/directories should be excluded while collecting tests. This is more powerful as it allows dynamic, runtime value as opposed to in `pyproject.toml`.

```
# conftest.py
collect_ignore = ["path/to/test/excluded"]
collect_ignore_glob = ["*_ignore.py"]
```

#### Remarks

As a side note, [`norecursedirs`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-norecursedirs) *may* be used for excluding some submodules or subdirectories but this would not be a good idea, because this should contain patterns to ignore some build artifacts or ignored directories, e.g., `_build`, `.venv`, `dist`, etc.